# Doing a variable substitution and saving the files

Tags: powershell

I want it to go though some folders recursivly, find all files with certain endings, and then go through found files to do the subsitute and then save. I can make it work when I have a given filename, but I seem to be haveing some trouble when it comes to the unknown.

The thought is to read the variables for a given environment from a file and save it into PowerShell as variables (this part seems to work, so I've not mentioned it again), then simply substitute the mentioned variables in a set of unknown files.

I've been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619699/add-text-to-multiple-files-via-powershell), which seemed to have something of a similar problem, except that I'm trying to use a variable substitusion. Also looked at some [previous answer for replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921462/powershell-listing-folders-in-mulitple-places-and-changing-files-in-those-plac), but again, this is not replace, but variable substitution, so it seems to work a bit differently. So with that in mind, this is what I got so far:

After looking at the examples in the first link:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Include *.ini,*.exe.config -Recurse | %{ gc $_ } | %{
  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_) +
    (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String ) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

After trying to do something with the second link:

```
    $places = 'C:\Users\Roger\Documents\test\Program Files (x86)'
    $places |
      Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.ini,*.config |
      ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content $_) | % {
          $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_) |
            Set-Content $_
          'Processed: {0}' -f $_.FullName
        }
}
```

And of course my own feeble attempts:

```
Get-ChildItem .\ -Include *.ini,*.exe.config -Recurse | %{ gc $_ } | %{
  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)
} | Set-Content $_.FullName
```

Comment: Your 2nd code sample is a closing curly bracket short, while the 3rd sample has one too many. Also, what do you want to substitute and what do you want to substitute it with? How are the actual results of your code samples different from the expected results?

Comment: Sometimes you just need more eyes. I tried correcting according to your comments @AnsgarWiechers hope it gets more clear. The 2nd sample actually completed running now, tough it seems to have created files based on the variables read into Powershell instead of changing the already existing ones.

Tough the 3rd sample still gives some error as "Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." So probably something with the formating I cannot see.

In any case I only want it to work as described. My code might be way off, or it might need adjustment, I don't know ...

Comment: It seems sample 2 actually works to a certain degree now. Just that after the variable substitute, the Set-Content doesn't seem to understand which file was actually used for the substituion, so Set-Content decides to make a new file with the name of the variable beeing substituted like "Database = ${DB_DRIVER}" I guess along the piping I loose the filename and path for the Set-Content command. I splitt the code up and found that the substitution of the lines in the files does take place, just ... the files are never saved as the files that the content was gotten from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$places = 'C:\temp'
$places |
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.ini,*.config | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object {
        $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)
    } | Set-Content $_
    'Processed: {0}' -f $_.FullName
}
```

Move the `Set-Content` out of the inside `ForEach-Object`. `Set-Content` would have been trying to fire for each line using the current line as its name as you have seen. Also, for yours and others sanity, you should try and be consistent with using aliases or not. I see both `ForEach-Object` and `%` which could be confusing to new users.

Comment: haha, I guess copy-paste and consistency isn't a good combination ;) Testing tends to take the wierdest paths. Gonna try out your solution now. And works excellent :) Thanks